# RuntimeWarning: Divide by Zero error: How to avoid? PYTHON, NUMPY

Tags: python, numpy

I am running in to RuntimeWarning: Invalid value encountered in divide

```
 import numpy
 a = numpy.random.rand((1000000, 100))
 b = numpy.random.rand((1,100))
 dots = numpy.dot(b,a.T)/numpy.dot(b,b)
 norms = numpy.linalg.norm(a, axis =1)
 angles = dots/norms ### Basically I am calculating angle between 2 vectors
```

There are some vectors in my a which have norm as 0. so while calculating angles it is giving runtime warning.

Is there a one line pythonic way to compute angles while taking into account norms which are 0?

```
angles =[i/j if j!=0 else -2 for i,j in zip(dots, norms)] # takes 10.6 seconds
```

But it takes a lot of time. Since all angles will have values between 1 and -1 and I need only 10 max values this will help me. This takes around 10.6 seconds which is insane.

Comment: can you filter norms before passing it?

Comment: No I want to preserve the indices because I want indices of 10 largest angles in the end which are further matched in other list. So preserving indices is must for me.

Comment: With the code you posted, the `angles` variable will have NaNs where `norms` is zero. Isn't that what you want? Note that if you want `None` instead of `NaN`, then you'll need to make `angles` of dtype `object`, which is bad for performance... (Also, it is possible to just suppress RuntimeWarnings. Is that what you want?)

Comment: I want specific value at place where NaN is encountered. So that I can manipulate it while sorting.

Comment: nans sort higher than anything else so when you are sorting you can just strip the top np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(d.ravel()) values

Comment: How is your code sorting it?

Comment: "one line pythonic way": write a little function, e.g. `div0` in [numpy-return-0-with-divide-by-zero/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248654/numpy-return-0-with-divide-by-zero/35696047#35696047)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can ignore warings with the `np.errstate` context manager and later replace nans with what you want:

```
import numpy as np
angle = np.arange(-5., 5.) 
norm = np.arange(10.)
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    print np.where(norm != 0., angle / norm, -2)
# or:
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    res = angle/norm
res[np.isnan(res)] = -2
```

Comment: Somehow my code keeps on saying : numpy.ndarray has no attribute where. WTF?

Comment: where is a function in numpy, it is not a method of an ndarray

Comment: my bad.. i should take sleep b4 working further. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 5):

In newer versions of numpy there is a third alternative option that avoids needing to use the errstate context manager.

All Numpy [ufuncs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) accept an optional "where" argument.  This acts slightly differently than the np.where function, in that it only evaluates the function "where" the mask is true.  When the mask is False, it doesn't change the value, so using the "out" argument allows us to preallocate any default we want.

```
import numpy as np

angle = np.arange(-5., 5.)
norm = np.arange(10.)

# version 1
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    res1 = np.where(norm != 0., angle / norm, -2)

# version 2
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    res2 = angle/norm
res2[np.isinf(res2)] = -2

# version 3
res3 = -2. * np.ones(angle.shape)
np.divide(angle, norm, out=res3, where=norm != 0)

print(res1)
print(res2)
print(res3)

np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(res1, res2)
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(res1, res3)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `angles[~np.isfinite(angles)] = ...` to replace `nan` values with some other value.

For example:

```
In [103]: angles = dots/norms

In [104]: angles
Out[104]: array([[ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan]])

In [105]: angles[~np.isfinite(angles)] = -2

In [106]: angles
Out[106]: array([[-2., -2., -2., ..., -2., -2., -2.]])
```

Note that division by zero may result in `inf`s, rather than `nan`s,

```
In [140]: np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 0])/np.array([1, 2, 0, -0., 0])
Out[140]: array([  1.,   1.,  inf, -inf,  nan])
```

so it is better to call `np.isfinite` rather than `np.isnan` to identify the places where there was division by zero.

```
In [141]: np.isfinite(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 0])/np.array([1, 2, 0, -0., 0]))
Out[141]: array([ True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

---

Note that if you only want the top ten values from an NumPy array, using the `np.argpartition` function may be quicker than fully sorting the entire array, especially for large arrays:

```
In [110]: N = 3

In [111]: x = np.array([50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0, 100, 90, 80, 70, 60])

In [112]: idx = np.argpartition(-x, N)

In [113]: idx
Out[113]: array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10,  0,  1,  4,  3,  2,  5])

In [114]: x[idx[:N]]
Out[114]: array([100,  90,  80])
```

This shows `np.argpartition` is quicker for even only moderately large arrays:

```
In [123]: x = np.array([50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0, 100, 90, 80, 70, 60]*1000)

In [124]: %timeit np.sort(x)[-N:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 233 µs per loop

In [125]: %timeit idx = np.argpartition(-x, N); x[idx[:N]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 53.3 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to be using `np.where`. See the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
angles = np.where(norms != 0, dots/norms, -2)
```

Angles will consist of `downs/norms` whenever `norms != 0`, and will be -2 otherwise. You will still get the RuntimeWarning, as `np.where` will still calculate the entire vector `dots/norms` internally, but you can safely ignore it.

Comment: Somehow it didn't give me any warning!!

Comment: If you're running python interactively (e.g. in ipython) then I believe it will only give you the warning once per session. You can also always add `np.errstate(divide='ignore')` as jtaylor suggested to suppress the warning in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.where( condition )`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero) to perform a conditional slice of where norms does not equal 0 before dividing:

```
norms = np.where(norms != 0 ) 
angles = dots/norms
```

Comment: norms is a vector and not number. I want to do element wise division of vectors with puting None where division is not possible