# How to fix some runtime warning in python?

Tags: python

I want to perform fitting using following `Fit_Curve` function but I'm getting the runtime error which may arise when the value of x is too small. But I don't want to change the value of x in my code. I read an answer related to this question that I need to perform sum simplification of fitting function. Is there any other way or easiest way to get rid of this error. Is it just a warning or is it an error? Does this warning effect my final result means fitting?

```
def Fit_Curve(x,a,beta,b,gamma):
   return (a*(x**beta)*np.exp(-b*(x**gamma)))
```

```
  matrix_check.py:105: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in 
   power return (a*(x**beta)*np.exp(-b*(x**gamma)))
```

Comment: matplotlib tag removed. Nothing to do with plotting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087769/runtimewarning-divide-by-zero-error-how-to-avoid-python-numpy).

Comment: Actually my question is different. I want to know if it is simple warning or error? How to get rid of this